# hibernate ManyToMany.Ошибка мапинга

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

Здравствуйте..помогите пжлста...
Есть главный класс (Entity) .В котором есть ссылки(колекции) на другие сущности.

```
@Entity
public class Projects {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long     id;
    private String ame;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="employee")
    private List<Employee> employee;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="projectLeader")
    private List<ProjectLeader> projectLeader;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="projectPerformers")
    private List<ProjectPerformers> projectPerformers;

  //get/set

}
```

Есть еще три остальных класса Entity.

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "employee")
    private List<Projects> projects; 
    //get/set...
}



@Entity
public class ProjectLeader {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "projectLeader")
    private List<Projects> projects;
//get/set...
}



@Entity
public class ProjectPerformers {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "projectPerformers")
    private List<Projects> projects;
//get/set...
}
```

А сохраняю вот так:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class DataService {
    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactoryDistant;
    Success s = new Success();

    private List<Employee> em = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    private List<ProjectLeader> pLeader = new ArrayList<ProjectLeader>();
    private List<ProjectPerformers> pPerformers= new ArrayList<ProjectPerformers>();


    public Object add(){
        Projects p = new Projects();
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        ProjectLeader projectLeader = new ProjectLeader();
        ProjectPerformers projectPerformers = new ProjectPerformers();


        p.setName("lalalProject");

        employee.setName("vinniPuh");

        projectLeader.setName("michael");

        projectPerformers.setName("progers");


        em.add(employee);
        pLeader.add(projectLeader);
        pPerformers.add(projectPerformers);


        p.setEmployee(em);
        p.setProjectLeader(pLeader);
        p.setProjectPerformers(pPerformers);

        sessionFactoryDistant.getCurrentSession().save(p);
        s.setResult("сохранено");
        return s;    
    }
}
```

Вот такая ошибка :

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.springapp.mvc.models.Employee; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.springapp.mvc.models.Employeeorg.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    root cause

    org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.springapp.mvc.models.Employee; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.springapp.mvc.models.Employeeorg.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:190)org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateTransactionManager.java:684)org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:566)org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:757)org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:726)org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:496)org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:276)org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)com.springapp.mvc.service.DataService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$35c7728e.add(<generated>)com.springapp.mvc.m_controllers.MainController.addProject(MainController.java:21)sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:781)org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:721)org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    root cause

    org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.springapp.mvc.models.Employeeorg.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.getEntityIdentifierIfNotUnsaved(ForeignKeys.java:294)org.hibernate.type.EntityType.getIdentifier(EntityType.java:537)org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.nullSafeSet(ManyToOneType.java:165)org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.writeElement(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:899)org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.recreate(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1308)org.hibernate.action.internal.CollectionRecreateAction.execute(CollectionRecreateAction.java:67)org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:463)org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:349)org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1222)org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425)org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:558)org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:757)org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:726)org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:496)org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:276)org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)com.springapp.mvc.service.DataService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$35c7728e.add(<generated>)com.springapp.mvc.m_controllers.MainController.addProject(MainController.java:21)sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:781)org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:721)org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.14 logs.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить `cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}` для всех аннотаций `@ManyToMany` в главном классе. Иначе вам нужно будет вручную сохранять каждый из `Entity`.

То есть

```
@Entity
public class Projects {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long     id;
    private String ame;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(name="employee")
    private List<Employee> employee;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(name="projectLeader")
    private List<ProjectLeader> projectLeader;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(name="projectPerformers")
    private List<ProjectPerformers> projectPerformers;

  //get/set

}
```

См. больше [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302802/object-references-an-unsaved-transient-instance-save-the-transient-instance-be)

Comment: А вообще сохранять 3 обьекта в одной транзакции в hibernate можно? Т.Е. вот такой вариант не обьязателен? : sessionFactorySave(employee);sessionFactorySave(projectPerformers);sessionFactorySave(projectPerformers);sessionFactorySave(projects);

Comment: T.E . каждый раз вызывать getCurrentSession для каждого обьекта

Comment: Можно, хотя проще вызвать getCurrentSession один раз и сохранить результат. А так транзакции на то и существуют, чтобы в них изменяли разные объекты.

Comment: Спасибо.все заработало.

Comment: Отметьте тогда, что ответ принят.

Comment: Пардон...забыл..нажимал не верхнюю , как всегда.)))))))